# Proper way to store all days of every month in database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to store such fields in the table as: the **ID of the employee**, **his last name and first name**, and **how many hours he worked on each day of the month.** For example, **March 1 - 6 hours**, **March 2 - 4 hours**, **March 3 - 4 hours**. The example I gave in the table below is how I imagine it, is there a way to store this data in a more convenient way to do it in **PostgreSQL**? And how to handle the situation when there are **30, 31, 28, or 29** days in the month?

| ID | Person`s Full name | 1.03.2023 | 2.03.2023 | 3.03.23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill Gates | 6 | 7 | 6 |
| 2 | Steve Jobs | 5 | 7 | 6 |

| Total worked hours |
| --- |
| 19 |
| 19 |

Comment: Let me ask you, how well do you understand _database normalization_? I don't want to sound rude or condescending, but do you understand why using columns like that (i.e. 1 column per day) is a very bad idea?

Comment: @Dai I understand that is a very bad idea, and that's why I asked this question. I want to know about ways how to store it in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonsWorkedHours (
    PersonId int  NOT NULL,
    Date     date NOT NULL,
    Hours    real NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_PersonsWorkedHours PRIMARY KEY ( PersonId, Date ), /* This composite PK ensures that PersonId+Date is always unique, so the same Person cannot have 2 or more rows with the same Date value */
    CONSTRAINT FK_Hours_to_People    FOREIGN KEY ( PersonId ) REFERENCES People ( PersonId ),
    CONSTRAINT UK_PersonsWorkedHours UNIQUE KEY  ( Date, PersonId ), /* this is a secondary-key for the benefit of Date-first queries, instead of PersonId-first queries. */

    CONSTRAINT CK_HoursPerDay CHECK ( Hours >= 0 AND Hours < 24 ),
    
    INDEX FX_People ( PersonId )
)
```

> And how to handle the situation when there are 30, 31, 28, or 29 days in the month?

You don't need to handle it: the `date` type handles this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use two tables: one for employees, and another to store work hours (and that table references its *master*):

```
create table employee
  (emp_id    number primary key,
   full_name varchar(30)
  );

create table work
  (work_id   number primary key,
   emp_id    number references employee (emp_id),
   c_date    date,
   hours     number
  );
```

Doing so, you'd enter as many rows into `WORK` table as necessary. For example, for dates when someone doesn't work (weekends, holidays, vacations), you wouldn't enter *anything* at all.

Certainly, apply any other constraints you want (valid number of hours, split full name into first and last name, etc.), but that's the general idea of how to do it.